# Always HIGHT line on Oscilloscope when UNO's Fast PWM TOP ICR1

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, pwm

I have been trying to get an answer my question for a 2 days *already. It's good for knowledge collecting and playing with different things, but there haven't been a solution so far.*

I'm trying to leverage the `HXT500` Servo with the `Fast PWM with a TOP ICR1`

I'm using the `DFRobot DFRduino UNO v3.0 (R3)` analog of the `Arduino UNO`. Based on [the `Atmega 328P-PU`](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf)

I have an `Oscilloscope till 5 MHz` as additional tool

### Question

1. Why the `Fast PWM, TOP ISC1` always has the HIGHT only on a oscilloscope
2. Why the Clock `Prescaler` doesn't work

### My investigations & observations

I activated the `PWM with TOP ICR1` but on my oscilloscope showed only a `5V straight line`, I checked different diapasons (horizontal bases) `(1a)`. [Connected to `pins 10 or 9`](http://arduino.zl3p.com/s_infa/pict/arduino_uno_pins.jpg). I assumed that my UNO works on `1 MHz` (9.2.1 Default Clock Source on Page 37) [and calculated](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HVU97dkSNjiICo6uoFb2yLl0UpHilEODdI35nwU51xE/edit?usp=sharing) ICR1, OCR1A:B for 0 and 180 degree.

```
     void setup() {
      // all as Ports (for outputs)
        DDRB=0xFF;
        DDRC=0xFF;
        DDRD=0xFF;
    
      // Table 16-4 on Page 141
      // Fast PWM TOP is ICR1
      TCCR1A|=(0<<WGM10)|(1<<WGM11);
      TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12);
      ICR1=2499;
      
      // Table 16-2 on Page 140
      // Clear OC1A/OC1B on Compare Match, set OC1A/OC1B at BOTTOM (non-inverting mode)
      TCCR1A|=(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1B1);
    
      // Table 16-5 on Page 143
      // clkI/O/8
      TCCR1B|=(0<<CS12)|(1<<CS11)|(0<<CS10); // (2a)
    }
    
    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
        // 90 degree
        OCR1A=299;
        OCR1B=299;  
      delay(1000);                      
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
        // 0 degree
        OCR1A=49;  
        OCR1B=49;  
      delay(1000);                      
    }
```

There I noticed the following issues:

- I tried different `Prescale`s - there weren't any differences `(2a)`
- I tried 1 MHz, 8 MHz, 16 MHz - straight HIGHT line

What I have tried next:

- To use an Example for Servo leveraging from Arduino IDE. It worked but as I understood it worked via Interrupts, not a Hardware solution
- To use Fast PWM, 9 & 10-bit. `(2a) Prescale`s didn't work - I had movement
- To use Fast PWM, 8-bit (with code adjustment and wrong angles). `(2a) Prescaler`s didn't work - I had movement

Comment: A 5MHz oscilloscope likely can not resolve a 5MHz square wave.  What you may see is a distorted wave closer to a sin wave than a square wave.  You may not see anything but the DC component of higher frequency signals.  I don't know why you only see 5 volts when you are expecting a wave form or voltage less than 5 volts.  There maybe something wrong with the code, hardware, connections or you may have your oscilloscope AC coupled.

Comment: @st2000, thanks for your attention and comment
The wave explanation - yes, it makes sense,  I   didn't think in this way, thanks 
Considering possible issues: connections - it's fine, because in another modes it works w/o changing these connections
hardware - possible, but I don't know how to check it, but with the Fast AWM 9-bit it works
Interestingly: there is the same/similar issue with Normal, CTC modes
Code - it would be easiest reason )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to set the `TCCR1A` and `TCCR1B` registers to `0` before your code as the [Arduino library sets the WGM10 bit](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/6ec80154cd2ca52bce443afbbed8a1ad44d049cb/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L305). Or change the first `|=` to a `=`. By leaving the WGM10 bit set, you get fast PWM mode, with TOP set to OCR1A. Combined with your other code, this would result in both pins having a 100% duty cycle.

So use

```
TCCR1A=(0<<WGM10)|(1<<WGM11);
TCCR1B=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12);
```

or

```
TCCR1A=0;
TCCR1B=0;
TCCR1A|=(0<<WGM10)|(1<<WGM11);
TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12);
```

Other than that, you code looks fine, and should give you a 800Hz signal.

PS `"I assumed that my UNO works on 1 MHz"`; no, the UNO runs at 16Mhz.

Comment: thanks. I very appreciate the time that you spent here.

I have tried and it started working, but with some shift, because there were that wrong assumption, that you mentioned, about the `System Clock Speed`

Currently, the `fast PWM TOP ICR1`, `Prescaler` work and the math is matched